# CSS how to solve -webkit- functions

Tags: css

I'm currently using this code taken from the Chrome settings page and it works great on Chrome.

```
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-perspective: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
```

The code does not work on IE and Firefox. How can I use this same code, but then on IE and Firefox?

Comment: Have you tried using the other vendor specific prefixes in addition to the webkit one? `-moz-`, `-ms-`, `-o-`? Not all properties are available to all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is deprecated [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) code.

Here's a prefixed version, generated with `last 10 versions` with Autoprefixer on [Play](http://pleeease.io/play/):

```
flex-align: center;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-perspective: 1px;
perspective: 1px;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
```

This doesn't include the other CSS in your original post, just the properties that need to be prefixed.